# for each loop in elseif condition not working

Tags: php

in my project in index file i have following code.

```
<?php
include "app/config.php";
$browser_t="web";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='index.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id=1') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id=2') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id=3') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id=4') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id=5') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
?>
```

i want to make it dynamic. so, i am using following query.

```
<?php
include "app/config.php";
$browser_t="web";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='index.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif ($query="SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query);
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo $page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$value;
    }) {  
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
```

it is displaying error and i don't know how it can be done?how to use foreach loop or while loop here?please help me.

```
<?php 

include "app/config.php";
$browser_t="web";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='index.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl;" ) ) > 0 )
{
    $result_data    =   mysql_fetch_row($result);
    foreach($result_data as $value) {
        $page_name ='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='courses?cosoff=cosoff') {
    include $browser_t.'/courses/index.php';
    }
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result2 =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM courses;" ) ) > 0 )
{
    $result_data2    =   mysql_fetch_row($result2);
    foreach($result_data2 as $value) {
        $page_name ='courses?cosoff=cosoff&cors_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/courses/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='admission?admi=admi') {
    include $browser_t.'/admission/index.php';
    }
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result3 =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM admission;" ) ) > 0 )
{
    $result_data3    =   mysql_fetch_row($result3);
    foreach($result_data3 as $value) {
        $page_name ='admission?admi=admi&admi_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/admission/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='facelities?face=face') {
    include $browser_t.'/facelities/index.php';
    }
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result4 =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM facelities;" ) ) > 0 )
{
    $result_data4    =   mysql_fetch_row($result4);
    foreach($result_data4 as $value) {
        $page_name ='facelities?face=face&face_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/facelities/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='events?eve=eve') {
    include $browser_t.'/events/index.php';
    }
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result5 =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM events;" ) ) > 0 )
{
    $result_data5    =   mysql_fetch_row($result5);
    foreach($result_data5 as $value) {
        $page_name ='avrodh.php?eve=eve&evt_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/events/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='career.php?car=car') {
    include $browser_t.'/career.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact.php?con=con') {
    include $browser_t.'/contact.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='config.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/config.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='campus_tour.php?nohead=nohead') {
    include $browser_t.'/campus_tour.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='gallery.php?nohead=nohead') {
    include $browser_t.'/gallery.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='stud_corner.php?nohead=nohead') {
    include $browser_t.'/stud_corner.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='404.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/404.php';
}
else
{
    include $browser_t.'/404.php';
}

?>
```

Comment: Show the erro message please.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_library-pack4\index.php on line 19

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($query);` is not use for fetching data from database!!

Comment: I think it is better to use a switch case statement in you scenario

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: minimize last five elseif condition in one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your this code

```
elseif ($query="SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query);
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo $page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$value;
    }) {  
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
```

with this

```
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl;" ) ) > 0 )
{
    $result_data    =   mysql_fetch_row($result);
    foreach($result_data as $value) {
        echo $page_name ='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';    
}
```

Comment: it is not working if i use two elseif condition like that. if i use two then first one replace second one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87740/discussion-between-divyesh-jesadiya-and-syed-suleman).

Comment: Your code seems fine. There is no error in it . what do you want now ?

Comment: every time it's incuding   include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';

Comment: Because `elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl;" ) ) > 0 )` might always be true.... and so it is breaking in this if...

Comment: any solution for that?

Comment: i done with this elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl;" ) ) > 0 && strpos($page_name,'about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id=') !== false)

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to write you query outside the if condition .

2) `$result=mysql_query($query)` is not use for fetching data from database!!.

3)Stop using mysql it is deprecated. You can use mysqli or PDO

4)To check error on page use

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

And change your code with

```
<?php
include "app/config.php";
$browser_t="web";
$query="SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

 $page_name1=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$row['id'];// assing to anothere variable

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='index.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name==$page_name1) {  
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
```

Comment: what if $row['option_value'] is array?

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ($page){
  case ($page ==''):
  case ($page) == 'index.php':
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';

    break;
  // an other case 
  default:
    // add your query here
    $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM  aboutus_tbl;"
    if( mysql_num_rows($result)> 0 ){
      $result_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
      foreach($result_data as $value) {
        echo $page_name ='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$value;
     }  
     include $browser_t.'/about/index.php'; 
    break; 
   }
```

hope this help.

Comment: He's not fetching the data in he's database.

Comment: Ooops, I missed that part, I updated the code to include the result. too many if statements make the code hard to read sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in here

```
elseif ($query="SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query);
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo $page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$value;
    }) {  
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in that code, but you can't have SQL queries and foreach loops in between the parenthesis of the `elseif`. The only thing you can have is an expression to be evaluated as `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include "app/config.php";
$browser_t="web";

$string = "";
$pg = "page_name";
$query =  "select id from task_assign";//your query goes here......
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($value = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
        $string .= "else if($$pg == 'about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$value[id])
        {
            include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
        }<br>";
}

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='index.php') {
   include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus') {
   include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
echo $string
```

Answer (score 0):

it's done like.......

```
<?php 
include "app/config.php";
$browser_t="web";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='index.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about?aboutus=aboutus') {
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';
}
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM aboutus_tbl;" ) ) > 0 && strpos($page_name,'about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id=') !== false)
{
    $result_data    =   mysql_fetch_row($result);
    foreach($result_data as $value) {
        $page_name ='about?aboutus=aboutus&aboutus_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/about/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='courses?cosoff=cosoff') {
    include $browser_t.'/courses/index.php';
    }
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM courses;" ) ) > 0 && strpos($page_name,'courses?cosoff=cosoff&cors_id=') !== false)
{
    $result_data    =   mysql_fetch_row($result);
    foreach($result_data as $value) {
        $page_name ='courses?cosoff=cosoff&cors_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/courses/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='admission?admi=admi') {
    include $browser_t.'/admission/index.php';
    }
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM admission_tbl;" ) ) > 0 && strpos($page_name,'admission?admi=admi&admi_id=') !== false)
{
    $result_data    =   mysql_fetch_row($result);
    foreach($result_data as $value) {
        $page_name ='admission?admi=admi&admi_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/admission/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='facelities?face=face') {
    include $browser_t.'/facelities/index.php';
    }
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM facelities;" ) ) > 0 && strpos($page_name,'facelities?face=face&face_id=') !== false)
{
    $result_data    =   mysql_fetch_row($result);
    foreach($result_data as $value) {
        $page_name ='facelities?face=face&face_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/facelities/index.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='events?eve=eve') {
    include $browser_t.'/events/index.php';
    }
elseif( mysql_num_rows( $result =   mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM event_content;" ) ) > 0 && strpos($page_name,'avrodh.php?eve=eve&evt_id=') !== false)
{
    $result_data    =   mysql_fetch_row($result);
    foreach($result_data as $value) {
        $page_name ='avrodh.php?eve=eve&evt_id='.$value;
    }  
    include $browser_t.'/events/avrodh.php';    
}
elseif ($page_name=='career.php?car=car') {
    include $browser_t.'/career.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact.php?con=con') {
    include $browser_t.'/contact.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='config.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/config.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='campus_tour.php?nohead=nohead') {
    include $browser_t.'/campus_tour.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='gallery.php?nohead=nohead') {
    include $browser_t.'/gallery.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='stud_corner.php?nohead=nohead') {
    include $browser_t.'/stud_corner.php';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='404.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/404.php';
    }
else
    {
        include $browser_t.'/404.php';
    }

?>
```